# Installing a major Ruby implementation without XCode

Tags: xcode, ruby

A user is wanting to get started with Ruby (and Ruby on Rails), and they don't have XCode installed, and the current internet connection is rather weak.

Are there any major implementations of Ruby (MRI, JRuby, Rubinius) that can be installed without installing XCode?

I know OS X comes with a system Ruby, but I've heard that "Don't touch nothing" is the best advice with regards to it.

Answer (score 1):

OS X includes the ruby interpreter it is in /usr/bin so on your path

On Yosemite

```
ruby --version
```

shows

```
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
```

Comment: That's what I was referring to with "system ruby".